# Planning out a LED driver 60v+ input, 36v 1a output

Tags: led, driver

I have 2 of 7070 (6 core) LEDs, that makes it 12 cores, all in series (should require 34-40v output there for) [led web page](https://www.pusatled.com/products/chip-led-7070-50w-6c-dual-putih-putih-mcp-biled-laser-rtd-aes-voxx-9v)

I want to build high efficiency DC-DC LED driver for them. Input is Li-Ion 14s battery (42-58.8v battery), so it will be Buck type.

I found few rather old but suitable I believe ICs

- mp4688 (looks like 93+% efficiency for my inV / outV)
- mp2489

Can any one give some advice? Perhaps there are some newer higher efficiency IC?

- LT8391 perhaps better?

Require:

- on/off via 1.5v or 10v signal
- no need for dimming
- 36-40w is enough
- Led driver needs to be efficient (no heating up)
- space is limited, cost anything below 40$ is fun project after all :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I’m running this now, but for some reason that tiny IC get super hot with in second from output half of what it should do, and even than ic should not over heat normally

So decided to try make my own. This one is nice you plug in any input up to 60v and any led series on output up to 56v requirement and it will give constant current to led with voltage it requires. (But also abit odd, give 34v to my 12 cores = I would expect 36v minimum)

Comment: The soldering on those shunt resistors is concerning, particularly as R1 is missing outright. Fixing that board is likely cheaper/easier than attempting a new design from scratch